# InstallShield silent install CR Runtime 13.0.17

Tags: installation, installshield, setup-project, installshield-2015

**Hi**, I create a Setup with Installshield 2015. my setup has a prerequisites for reporting viewer so i want to install CR_Runtime13.0.17.msi silently. for this situation we want a command to start the cr_runtime setup silent, after many searches on the net i found this command.

```
msiexec /i IsSetupPrerequisites\CR_Runtime13\CR_Runtime13.0.17.msi /qb /norestart
```

when i use this command on Cmd it works well and setup is begins silently with progress bar but when i use this command on installshield, it show me an error and a help every time.

please help me to create a command for installshield to install cr_runtime13.0.17 silently.

at the end i Attached installshield command page and my help to this Question.

Many Thanks to all

[image: InstallShield Image]

[image: Setup Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **Specify the command line for the application** value is really just the arguments. From [Specifying Command-Line Parameters for an InstallShield Prerequisite](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield23helplib/installshield23helplib.htm#helplibrary/SetupPrereqEditorCmdLine.htm):

> Type any valid parameters for the file that is selected in the **Specify the application you wish to launch** list. Do not include the name of the file in this box.

Remove your inclusion of msiexec and an attempted relative path to the msi, leaving you with just `/qb /norestart`, and you should avoid the msiexec error. If that one still gives you problems, consider replacing `/norestart` with [`REBOOT=ReallySuppress`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371101).

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks For Your Answer. 
i remove my inclusion of msiexec and every thing is going well.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create a prerequisite for .net 4.6.1 and it worked silently when I had only /q /norestart in the command line and command line for silent mode.(instead of /qb /norestart)